# Swift: TableView make not selectable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I have a TableView in swift that is currently selectable and and allows the users to scroll. I want to make it so the user cannot interact with it and so it automatically scrolls. Think something similar to a stock feed that is constantly running through 500~ stocks and their price. How would I do this in swift?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BucketTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var buckets = [NSDictionary]()

    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        buckets = [...]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buckets.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BucketTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
        })
    }
}
```

The data is taken from the buckets array which is roughly 500~ long. How would I do this?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean from this? buckets = [...]

Comment: There is an extraordinary difference between "roughly 500~" and "infinite".

Answer (score 7):

You can disable user interaction by;

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = False
```

And for scrolling use this method: [scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:)

Comment: Where do I set:  scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: True? TableViewController - ViewDidLoad??

Comment: Where ever you want. Its a method. You can call it when you want the table view to scroll to a specific row